# How a Procfile is different from shellscript file and when should I use it?

Tags: proc, akka-http

In akk-http-microservice i have seen a procfile for the first time. I try to know about it.  I came to know that procfile is meant for executing commands. But how it differs from shell script which also do same. When should i prefer to it?

Answer (score 0):

A Procfile is a mechanism for declaring what commands are run by your application's dynos on the Heroku platform. It follows the process model. You can use a Procfile to declare various process types, such as multiple types of workers, a singleton process like a clock, or a consumer of the Twitter streaming API. Thus it's not related to Akka-Http.